# Why do I get Type Error when trying to plot with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, typeerror

I usually use jupiter to run matplotlib scripts but this time when compiling it using the terminal I get a massive error that I have not seen before.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3]
y = [1,2,3]

plt.plot(x,y)
```

I tried to uninstall and reinstall the package but that did not work. I am unsure on how to proceed.

The error I get is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Rogelio Medel\OneDrive\CODECADEMY\PERSONAL PROJECTS\Matplotlib2\testy.py", line 6, in <module>
    plt.plot(x,y)
  File "C:\Users\Rogelio Medel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2730, in plot
    return gca().plot(
  File "C:\Users\Rogelio Medel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2227, in gca
    return gcf().gca()
  File "C:\Users\Rogelio Medel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 832, in gcf
    return figure()
  File "C:\Users\Rogelio Medel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\deprecation.py", line 454, in wrapper       
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rogelio Medel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 773, in figure
    manager = new_figure_manager(
  File "C:\Users\Rogelio Medel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 348, in new_figure_manager      
    _warn_if_gui_out_of_main_thread()
  File "C:\Users\Rogelio Medel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 338, in _warn_if_gui_out_of_main_thread
    if (_get_required_interactive_framework(_get_backend_mod()) and
  File "C:\Users\Rogelio Medel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 207, in _get_backend_mod        
    switch_backend(dict.__getitem__(rcParams, "backend"))
  File "C:\Users\Rogelio Medel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 252, in switch_backend
    switch_backend(candidate)
  File "C:\Users\Rogelio Medel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 265, in switch_backend
    backend_mod = importlib.import_module(
  File "C:\Users\Rogelio Medel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Rogelio Medel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qtagg.py", line 12, in <module> 
    from .backend_qt import QtCore, QtGui, _BackendQT, FigureCanvasQT
  File "C:\Users\Rogelio Medel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt.py", line 72, in <module>    
    _MODIFIER_KEYS = [
  File "C:\Users\Rogelio Medel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt.py", line 73, in <listcomp>  
    (_to_int(getattr(_enum("QtCore.Qt.KeyboardModifier"), mod)),
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'KeyboardModifier'
```

Comment: That appears to be an issue with your matplotlib installation.  You might be able to work around it by choosing a different [backend](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/backends.html).

Comment: @NathanMills They seem similar, although in that question the error happens when importing, not when plotting.

Comment: @Barmar, it's the same exception and exception message, proximally at the evaluation of the same code in the same file.  Although the two examples get there by different routes, ultimately they are both happening during importing module `matplotlib.backends.backend_qt`.  Although it's conceivable that that module had two distinct bugs that manifest identically, it seems a lot more plausible that it's the same bug.